# Compare char arrays and print the lowest values

Tags: java, arrays

I wrote this code to compare two char arrays and print the less one every time.

```
public class CompareCharArrays {
    public void buildingArrays() {
        char[] a={'a','b','c','d'};
        char[]b={'l','f','a','g'};
        char[]c=new char[8];
        for(int i=0; i<c.length;i++){
            if(a[i]<b[i]){
                c=a;
                System.out.println("Element from array a: "+c[i]);
            } else {
                c=b;
                System.out.println("Element from array b: "+c[i]);
            }       
       }
 }
```

What's wrong with my program and how can I fix it ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: what do you mean less one every time?

Comment: You probably need to define "less one" (also note that `a[7]<b[7]` is going to hurt)

Comment: **"What's wrong with my program..."** -- Good question.  Are we supposed to guess?  Or are you going to tell us what the problem is?

Comment: You don't need `c` at all, it is just introducing an `ArrayOutOfBoundException` in your code.

Comment: No, brothers! I want to compare each elements in these two arrays: for example a[0] with b[0].If a[0] is less than b[0] i print first the smaller element and after that the bigger.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a,b are the same length, you want to compare each element of a to an element of b - so your iteration limit should be the length of a (or of b - identical by assumption here)

If they are not the same length, iterate over the length of the shorter, and then just output the remaining values from the longer.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do the following :

```
public class CompareCharArrays {
    public void buildingArrays() {
        char[] a = {'a','b','c','d'};
        char[] b = {'l','f','a','g'};
        for(int i=0 ; i<a.length ; i++)
            System.out.println("Element from array " + (a[i] < b[i] ? "a : " + a[i] : "b : " + b[i]);               
   }
}
```

You don't need to use an third variable `c`, especially if you use it like you did, initializing it with a length different from the two other arrays' length, throwing an `ArrayOutOfBoundException`.

Comment: your answer has been flagged as low quality answer, please provide some information

Answer (score 0):

c need not to be 8 length but 4.
you did c=a, but you meant c[i]=a[i]

correcting both this mistakes leads to this:

```
        char[] a={'a','b','c','d'};
        char[] b={'l','f','a','g'};
        char[] c= new char[4];
        for(int i=0; i<c.length;i++){
            if(a[i]<b[i]){
                c[i]=a[i];
                System.out.println("Element from array a: "+c[i]);
            } else {
                c[i]=b[i];
                System.out.println("Element from array b: "+c[i]);
            }
        }
```

c is then set to a, b, a, d.

Comment: Thank you! The problem is that: This code and the previous give me only 4 chars. I need the all 8 chars. How can i make that? Maybe i must include both arrays in third array, and after that to compare the elements step by step?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys! I owe you. I think this part of code is closer to the real conclussion:)

```
public class CompareCharArrays {
public void biuldingArrays() {
    char[] a={'a','b','c','d'};
char[]b={'l','f','a','g'};
for(int i=0; i<a.length;i++){
System.out.println("The first element is :"+(a[i] < b[i] ? "a : " + a[i]+" "+b[i] : "b : " + b[i]+  " "+ a[i]));  
 }  }
}
```

Thank you for the support again :)